# TFS 2018 - Full text search

Tags: search, tfs, full-text-search, wiki

I am starting to create Wiki in my TFS 2018 Update 2 and I find the problem of making full searches of both the content of the wiki and the attachments you may have (content of PDF, DOCX, etc).
Is it possible to enable the search function within the attachments?

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for now. You can  use wiki search to quickly find **relevant wiki pages by title** or **page content across all projects** in your TFS.

Take a look at this blog contain the detail Introduction-- [Announcing public preview of Wiki search](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/12/01/announcing-public-preview-of-wiki-search/)

If you really need this feature, you could submit a [uservoice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM and Admin will kindly review your suggestion.